# How to generate new template type each function call?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to figure out is that possible to auto generate template type of function depending on number calls of that function?

```
template<class T>
class A {
// some logic here
};

// smth is auto genearted type from may be count of calls f()?
template<class T = smth>
int f(int var) {
    return A<T>::patch(a);
}

int main() {
    int var = 0;

    // each function call without explicit template type generates unique type T
    var = f(var); 
    var = f(var);
    var = f(var);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what do you expect to happen when the same template function gets called from multiple translation units? What is the problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about making a template parameter work this way, but the problem to which you believe the solution is to make the template parameter work this way, so that's what you're asking about. What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that’s not possible. Template sublanguage is [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), i.e. there is no state: template is entirely defined by its arguments.

But if a macro may be suitable, use `__COUNTER__`. In the scope of a translation unit (of course), it expands to a new unique value each time it is used. So e.g. in the following code, the `fn` template is instantiated for three different values of `n`:

```
#define MY_FN (fn<__COUNTER__>)

template <int n>
void fn();

int main() {
    MY_FN();
    MY_FN();
    MY_FN();
}
```

You can even use `__COUNTER__` to generate unique variable names using token pasting, if desired so.